# comparing name of gameobject to its parent name

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
GameObject no=GameObject.Find("LevelButton");
GameObject noparent=GameObject.Find("LevelPHwithrect (" + (i + 1) + ")");
```

The problem is that I am able to find the `gameobjects`, but when I call

```
if(no.transform.parent.name==noparent.transform.name)
{
    //do something
}
```

I get an error saying null reference, even when it's finding the object and I have set parent of no to noparent.

Please forgive me if there are errors in this post, as this is my first day on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `name` property of the `GameObject`, not `Transform`.  Also code defensively and check for `null`:

```
if (no != null && noparent != null && no.name == noparent.name)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script attached to the "no" gameobject, try to use:

```
this.gameObject.name == this.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.name
```

`GameObject.Find` is kind of dangerous, since you can easily misspell or change the name of the gameobject in the Unity Interface and forget to change it in code. May I ask why you need this snippet ?

Comment: thanks man,i wanted to do actions in no ,found it in different way,thanks for the help

Comment: You can select one answer as correct (use the check mark on the left). If none helped you, add your own answer and check it. You can also upvote answers that you find adequate.